# Is there a mistake made by me?

Tags: python, python-class

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.number = num
    
    def square(self):
        print(f"The Square value of {self.num} is {self.number**2}")

a = Calculator(3)
a.square()
```

Comment: You use `self.num` in your f-string but the only attribute is `self.number`

Answer (score 1):

You're using "self.num" instead of "self.number":

```
def square(self):
    print(f"The Square value of {self.number} is {self.number**2}")
```

For the future please note that you need to increase the quality of the questions.
Post the error messages you're getting, what have you already tried and try to frame the questions  "how to fix this error message" format.[Take a look at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)